# JPEGCodec - package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

> Error:(15,32) java: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist

проблема вот с таким кодом

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeImageHandler;
import net.sourceforge.barbecue.linear.code39.Code39Barcode;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGEncodeParam;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;

public class BarImage {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BarImage.class);

    public static final Image empty = createEmptyImage(); 

....



        try
        {
            FileOutputStream baos = new FileOutputStream("c:/test1.jpg");
            JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(baos);
            JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(bi);
            param.setQuality(1f, true);//1f = JPG_QUALITY
            encoder.encode(bi, param);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
}
```

При сборке maven, проект не хочет собираться из-за такой ошибки.
 при этом пакет

**com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.**

существует в пакете **rt.jar**

проект старый и переделать пока невозможно, так как непонятно как взаимодействуют между собой модули.
 проект переводится с Ant на maven

может можно заменить com.sun.image.codec.jpeg ???

Что можно сделать ?

решение нашел такое:
 нужно подправить файл **pom.xml**

```java
 <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <compilerArgs>
              <arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вратце, то пакеты `com.sun.*` это приватный API, и использовать их не стоит. В современных версиях Java от них могут отказаться совсем.

Об этом же на английском, и подробнее. Там же можно найти подсказку, чем заменить `com.sun.image.codec.jpeg`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163091/package-com-sun-image-codec-jpeg-does-not-exist

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906673/import-com-sun-image-codec-jpeg